# How to use Eval function in the query string in a databind control like list view

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding, eval

How to use `Eval` function in the query string in a databind control like list view .

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink12" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval('<%#Eval("bal")%>', "Rep_calc.aspx?year={0}") %>'> <%#Eval("bal")%></asp:HyperLink>
```

---

I want to eval the `year` with `<%#Eval("bal")%>` value .How to do this ?

Comment: what is your expected value for NavigateUrl attribute?

Comment: `Rep_calc.aspx?year=`+bal_value`
some thing like that 
`Rep_calc.aspx?year=2013`

Comment: Try using this NavigateUrl='<%# "Rep_calc.aspx?year=" + Eval("bal")%>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "Rep_calc.aspx?year=" + Eval("bal")%>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink12" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# EvaluateYear(Eval("bal")) %>'><%#Eval("bal").toString() %></asp:HyperLink>
```

and then in your code behind:

```
public string EvaluateYear(object bal)
{
    return Eval(bal.ToString(), "Rep_calc.aspx?year={0}");
}
```

You may want to cast bal to it's datatype if you wish, but that might not make any difference.

Comment: what should the `object bal` cuz the `bal` is a part of datatable which is the datasource of my listview

Comment: Yeah, every time a row gets bound the function will be called, and the  object will be passed. The parameter needs to be object...

Comment: Do u mean if the bal column in the datatable has the following values `2013,2014,2015` then i have to create `List<int>` as an object ?

Comment: Will just one row have 3 different years? Or just one?

Comment: no three rows each row has a value for the column `bal`

Comment: Then the code as I gave it to you should work... Does it work at all? You getting any errors?

Comment: `bal.ToString()` cannot cast list to string how to get the proper value ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48234/discussion-between-hanlet-escano-and-just-name)

Answer (score 0):

target="_blank" href='<%# "/SR-Forecasting/OBOverrides.aspx?OBOverrideID="+Eval("Override_ID_OB") %>'

Try this it will work

Comment: explain little bit and highlight main suggestion or code in ``